# Visual Studio 2017 - How to reference Library to some part of a project?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reference, nuget

What is the way in VS to reference `gudusoft.gsqlparser` to some part of a project?

e.g. found online this library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/gudusoft.gsqlparser/

but did not find DLL - only nuget..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2017 - How to reference Library to some part of a project?

You can use NuGet to install this online library to your project.

To use NuGet:

Right on your project, select `Manage NuGet Packages...`, switch to the `Browse` tab in the open window, type `gudusoft.gsqlparser` in the search bar, then click `Install` button:

[image]

Then NuGet will add the `.dll` to your project.

Of course, you can aslo add this .dll file directly to your project manually. You just need download that online this library:

https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/gudusoft.gsqlparser/3.2.6.5

Then rename it with `*.zip` and unzip it, you will find the dll file in the lib folder, you can add it to your project directly.

Hope this helps.